# MudTable WASM, populating state on page load

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Can't find a code sample for this in any of the documentation.  Using MudTable ServerData feature, want to store the tables state (page no, page size, sorting) into the url as it changes which Iv'e done:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/list/MyEntity/?PageNo={state.Page}&PageSize={state.PageSize}&SortLabel={state.SortLabel}&SortDirection={(state.SortDirection == MudBlazor.SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc")}&Filter={Filter}", false);
```

However on loading the page, I want to push these parameters into the MudTable

```
            table.CurrentPage = PageNo;
            table.RowsPerPage = PageSize;
            
           await table.ReloadServerData();
```

however I get warnings that I can't use 'table.CurrentPage' outside of component.  Any way to implement what I want in current version of MudTable?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the values to component parameters in code is not the Blazor way. All you need  to do is to set them in Razor like this:

```html
<MudTable Items="@Elements" CurrentPage="PageNo" RowsPerPage="PageSize">
    ...
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
```

Here is a fiddle to play around with live. It shows that setting the two parameters in razor works. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaQlvFvLmZkKlaWQ

Comment: Thanks, I've tweaked your code sample which had some bugs, and updated the link.  Not  had a chance to test with with server data call yet, also doesn't cover adding the sorting from the url either which I'm quickly coming to conclusion is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do the trick. Sadly, [NavigateTo() looks broken](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/3017).

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<MudTable
    @* ... *@
</MudTable>

@code
{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // on first render, _table is null
        if (firstRender)
        {
            return;
        }

        var uri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavigationManager.Uri);
        var queryComponents = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
        queryComponents.TryGetValue("PageNo", out StringValues pageNo);
        queryComponents.TryGetValue("PageSize", out StringValues pageSize);

        int rowsPerPage = int.Parse(pageSize.First());
        int page = int.Parse(pageNo.First());

        _table.SetRowsPerPage(rowsPerPage);
        //_table.NavigateTo(page);    // this is broken

        await _table.ReloadServerData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn’t answer the question! Try it and you should get same warning I mentioned in question regarding calling CurrentPage outside of component

Comment: Ok I think I nailed it this time. SetRowsPerPage() is working correctly but like I said, NavigateTo() is broken.